# How to create Content Fragments from JSON descriptions? (AEM 6.3)

Tags: aem, aem-6

I am new to AEM and need a high level understanding of this use case before diving deep into the coding specifics.

I want to programmatically create new Content Fragments using data from external authoring systems.

The content will be supplied as a zip containing both a formatted html version and a JSON file describing the structure (no styling info) plus any media assets referenced in the html/JSON.

Desired AEM functionality:
- unpack zip
- ingest assets to DAM
- create new content fragment from predefined content fragment model
- use JSON structure to complete content fragment (data will be consistent and cf model designed to suit) and reference assets in DAM

Stretch goals:
- create new experience fragments based on the new content fragment (using metadata in JSON?)
- create new draft page placing the content or experience fragment into a component

What is the best way to ingest and automate this content? Research so far suggests a workflow. I am keen to understand the more detail on how this is done and any examples available.

I will be starting with 6.3 so there are no legacy issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the contentFragmentManager from the API. 
[Content Fragment Manager  API](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/adobe/cq/dam/cfm/ContentFragmentManager.html)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to get some insight on the best process leading up to calling that API.I assume the API is called using custom java code as part of a workflow?

Comment: Yes, you can use the Unarchiver step for the extraction, and for the creation of the content fragments you need to create a workflow step that takes as a payload each item in the zipfile, and use the API for the creation of the items.